# Bean Validation not working

Tags: spring, validation, rest, cxf, javabeans

I have a `Reservation` service that makes reservations using request-response and DAO patterns. I'm trying to build a simple REST API using Spring that allows me to create, search, edit and delete info about the reservations. Info is sent and returned via JSON. The problem is that I'm trying to use Bean Validation and the service seems to completely ignore it.

**Reservation.java**

```
package org.prueba01.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class Reservation {

    private int id;

    @NotNull(message="El nombre es obligatorio.")
    @NotEmpty(message="El nombre no puede estar vacio.")
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message="Es obligatorio indicar el numero de personas.")
    @NotEmpty(message="El numero de personas no puede estar vacio.")
    @Length(min=1, max=15, message="El numero de personas debe ser entre 1 y 15.")
    private int people;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
    public void setPeople(int people) {
        this.people = people;
    }   

}
```

**ReservationRequest.java**

```
package org.prueba01.model;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class ReservationRequest {

    @NotNull(message="No puede haber campos nulos.")
    @NotEmpty(message="No puede haber campos vacios.")
    @Valid
    private Reservation reservation;

    public Reservation getReservation(){
        return reservation;
    }

    public void setReserva (Reservation reservation){
        this.reservation=reservation;
    }

}
```

**ReservationResponse.java**

```
package org.prueba01.model;

import java.util.List;

public class ReservationResponse {

    private List<Reservation> reservations;
    private String errorMsg;    
    private boolean success=true;

    public List<Reservation> getReservations(){
        return reservations;
    }

    public void setReservations (List<Reservation> reservations){
        this.reservations=reservations;
    }

    public Boolean isSuccess(){
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess (boolean success){
        this.success=success;
    }

    public String getErrorMsg(){
        return errorMsg;
    }

    public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg){
        this.errorMsg=errorMsg;
    }

}
```

**IReservationDao.java**

```
package org.prueba01.reservation.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.prueba01.model.Reservation;

    public interface IReservationDao {

        public Reservation searchReservation(int id);
        public List<Reservation> showAll();
        public void addReservation(Reservation reservation);
        public void changeReservation(Reservation reservation);
        public void cancelReservation (int id);
    }
```

**ReservationDaoImpl.java**

```
package org.prueba01.reservation.dao.impl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.prueba01.model.Reservation;
import org.prueba01.reservation.dao.IReservationDao;

public class ReservationDaoImpl implements IReservationDao {

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    List<Reservation> reservations = new ArrayList<Reservation>();

    public Reservation searchReservation (int id){
        for (Reservation reservation : reservations){
            if (reservation.getId()==id){
                return reservation;
            }
        }

        throw new RuntimeException ("Reserva con el id " +id + " no encontrada!");
    }

    public List<Reservation> showAll(){
        return reservations;
    }

    public void addReservation (Reservation reservation){
        reservations.add(reservation);
        reservation.setId(counter.getAndIncrement());

    }

    public void changeReservation (Reservation reservation){
        Reservation reservationToChange = searchReservation(reservation.getId());

        reservationToChange.setId(reservation.getId());
        reservationToChange.setName(reservation.getName());
        reservationToChange.setPeople(reservation.getPeople());
    }

    public void cancelReservation(int id){
        Reservation reservationToCancel = searchReservation(id);        
        reservations.remove(reservationToCancel);
    }
}
```

**ReservationManager.java**

```
package org.prueba01.manager;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.prueba01.model.ReservationRequest;
import org.prueba01.model.ReservationResponse;

public interface ReservationManager {

    @GET
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/searchReservation/{a}")
    public ReservationResponse searchReservation(
    @PathParam ("a")
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "El id de la reserva debe ser un valor numerico.")
    int id);

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/showAll/")  
    public ReservationResponse showAll();   

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/addReservation/")
    @NotNull(message="No puede haber campos nulos.")
    @NotEmpty(message="No puede haber campos vacios.")
    @Valid
    public ReservationResponse addReservation(ReservationRequest request);

    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/changeReservation/")
    @NotNull(message="No puede haber campos nulos.")
    @NotEmpty(message="No puede haber campos vacios.")
    @Valid
    public ReservationResponse changeReservation(ReservationRequest request);

    @DELETE
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/cancelReservation/{a}")
    public ReservationResponse cancelReservation(
    @PathParam ("a")        
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]+", message = "El id de la reserva debe ser un valor numerico.")
    int id);

}
```

**ReservationManagerService.java**

```
package org.prueba01.manager.impl;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.prueba01.manager.ReservationManager;
import org.prueba01.model.ReservationRequest;
import org.prueba01.model.ReservationResponse;
import org.prueba01.reservation.dao.IReservationDao;

public class ReservationManagerService implements ReservationManager {

    private IReservationDao reservationDao;

    public IReservationDao getReservationDao(){
        return reservationDao;
    }

    public void setReservationDao (IReservationDao reservationDao){
        this.reservationDao=reservationDao;
    }

    public ReservationResponse searchReservation(int id){
        ReservationResponse response = new ReservationResponse();

        try{
            response.setReservations(Arrays.asList(getReservationDao().searchReservation(id)));
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setErrorMsg(e.getClass()+": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    public ReservationResponse showAll(){
        ReservationResponse response = new ReservationResponse();

        try {
            response.setReservations(getReservationDao().showAll());
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setErrorMsg(e.getClass()+": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    public ReservationResponse addReservation(ReservationRequest request){
        ReservationResponse response = new ReservationResponse();

        try{
            getReservationDao().addReservation(request.getReservation());
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setErrorMsg(e.getClass()+": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    public ReservationResponse changeReservation (ReservationRequest request){
        ReservationResponse response = new ReservationResponse();

        try{
            getReservationDao().changeReservation(request.getReservation());
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setErrorMsg(e.getClass()+": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;

    }

    public ReservationResponse cancelReservation (int id){
        ReservationResponse response = new ReservationResponse();

        try{
            getReservationDao().cancelReservation(id);
        }

        catch (Exception e){
            response.setSuccess(false);
            response.setErrorMsg(e.getClass()+": " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.pruebas</groupId>
  <artifactId>prueba01</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>prueba01 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>prueba01</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
        xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
        xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <cxf:bus>
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>

    <bean id="reservationDao" 
        class="org.prueba01.reservation.dao.impl.ReservationDaoImpl">
    </bean>

    <bean id="reservationManagerService" 
        class="org.prueba01.manager.impl.ReservationManagerService">
        <property name="reservationDao" ref="reservationDao"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonProvider" 
        class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>

    <jaxrs:server id="reservationManagerDao" address="/rest/ReservationManager">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="reservationManagerService"/>
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean='jsonProvider' />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    metadata-complete="true">

    <display-name>Rest Test</display-name>
    <description>Rest Test</description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've tried with both Apache 7 an 8 versions. Requests are made via

> localhost:8080/prueba01/services/rest/ReservationManager/REST_CALL

and all of them seem to work fine. But if I try to test any of the Bean Validations; for instance, sending a POST Request to

> localhost:8080/prueba01/services/rest/ReservationManager/addReservation

with a partially empty JSON like

> {"reservation":{"people":"3"}}

The service works normally and it introduces a null value to the "name" value, instead of crashing the service. Any ideas why this could be happening?

NOTE 1: I have also cxf-2.7.6 jar added to my lib folder, as I can't use it via Maven, don't know why.

NOTE 2: I haven't tried to handle the Bean Validation Exceptions yet, because I'm just trying to make sure they take place for now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to follow the ValidationFeature documentation provided by CXF ? 
Maybe that can solve your problem :
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/validationfeature.html#ValidationFeature-CommonBeanValidation1.1Interceptors

Another solution is to manually validate the request with a Validator. I can provide you an example if the first solution doesn't work.

Have a good day.